# How to create a txt file from a string with exactly whats what is in the string?

Tags: javascript, html, string, download, txt

I have created a simple HTML file that has a textarea, two text input, and a button that when the button is clicked it downloads what is in the textarea with what is in the text input as the name. This has worked for me a very long time until I typed text with a #. When I put the # it would create the txt file with only the stuff before the #. This is the code for how I download it.

```js
function generate() {
    var textToSave = document.getElementById('Input1').value;
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

    hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(textToSave);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = document.getElementById('fileName').value+'.' + document.getElementById("fileExtension").value;
    hiddenElement.click();
}
```

I can't use anything but the #, so I need a way for the file to keep all the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with [a blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Blob_constructor_example_usage) :

```
var textToSave = document.getElementById('Input1').value;

var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

hiddenElement.download = 'string.txt';
var blob = new Blob([textToSave], {
    type: 'text/plain'
});
hiddenElement.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
hiddenElement.click();
```